# Understanding this matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, proof-explanation

> I wish to understand this step from the proof of the spectral norm being equal to the largest singular value

I am trying to show that the lower bound of $\|A\|_{2}\geq\sigma_{\text{max}}$. There is a trick here that uses the Schur Jordan's decomposition. So let us say that $y\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$ where $A^{T}A=QDQ^{T}$. Now there is this curious inequality in one of the steps of the proof :
$$
\sqrt{y^{T}A^{T}Ay}\geq\sqrt{y^{T}\sigma_{\text{max}}^{2}y}
$$
I want to know how we can show this is true. I tried to rewrite the left hand side as :
$$
\sqrt{y^{T}QDQ^{T}y}
$$
I also sketched it and what appears to be is that $y^{T}Q$ will output a row vector which is greater than $y^{T}$, Moreover, the same thing can be said about $Q^{T}y>y$. Lastly, the diagonal matrix when multiply by $y^{T}Q$ and then multiplied to $Q^{T}y$ should output a scalar much larger than multiplying $y^{T}$ by a diagonal matrix having just one element $\sigma_{max}^{2}$ so does this intuition make sense? how can we show this mathematically?

Comment: What is your definition of spectral norm and what is your definition of singular value? In most settings, the singular values of $A$ are *defined* as the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$.

Comment: Hello, the definition is $$\|A\|_{2}=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{2}}{\|x\|_{2}}=\max_{\|x\|_{2}=1}\|Ax\|_{2}$$ and yes the singular values are the square root of the eigenvalues of $A^{T}A$ @angryavian

Comment: My question is basically how we made the comparison between $y^{T}QDQ^{T}y$ and $y^{T}\sigma_{\text{max}}^{2}y$

Comment: If $y$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $\lambda_{\max}$ (the maximum eigenvalue of $A^\top A$) then $y^\top A^\top A y = y^\top (\lambda_{\max} y)$ and $\lambda_{\max} = \sigma^2_{\max}$.